# Undefined Reference to `Class::Class Constructor'

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, subclass

I am trying to create an array of objects with the class **Sqr** which is derived from **Rect**. But I am getting this error - **undefined reference to `Sqr::Sqr()'**. This is the code -

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Rect
{
    float length, bredth;
public:
    Rect();
    Rect(float l, float b) : length(l), bredth(b){}
};

class Sqr : public Rect
{
public:
    Sqr();
    Sqr(float side) : Rect(side, side){}
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    Sqr ss[10];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `Sqr::Sqr()` defined? Or `Rect::Rect()`? All I can see, are declarations for those.

Comment: Just search for the error next time.

Comment: `Sqr();` declaration. `Sqr(){}` definition and declaration.

Comment: Strange thing is that you have correctly defined `Sqr::Sqr(float side)`. Can you not see the difference with `Sqr::Sqr()`?

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the short explanation I fixed it now. I am new to cpp that is why I am confused in this type of things :")